# Where to find android crash history

Tags: android, crash, crash-dumps

I've been experiencing a great deal of instability on my Verizon Galaxy S III, and I believe it's related to the WiFi driver, or at least something in the networking stack. I get daily full system crashes that cause soft reboots of the OS.

In order to trace to the root of the issue, I'd like to see historical crash data for the Android OS. Please note that I am NOT developing an app, and I do not want instruction on how to use LogCat to trace issues within an in-development app. I want to see the Android system crash logs, but I'm not sure where to look for them.

Comment: Some issue with a rooted device (CyanogenMod).  Any method to get any crash logs there?

Comment: I know you don't want to use logcat but maybe there is an app out there that could record only crashes based off logcat.

Comment: I presume you mean "same issue" and once we get our answer, I'd imagine it will be in the same location for stock and custom ROMs

Comment: I have nothing against LogCat, and I imagine it will be how I view the crash dumps. I just wanted to clarify that I'm not looking for crashing in an in-development app, since there are already many SO posts about that.

Comment: Have you tried downloading [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd) from the market? Though I am not sure it would write a log to your memory if the system reboots... Just trying to help if I can

Comment: @Asok custom log apps won't work on 4.1

Comment: @Mighter +1, I wasn't aware, thanks. That's a bummer.

Comment: well, I'm running 4.1 and have no problem using aLogcat.

Comment: @edthethird on 4.1 it will only show you messages which are related to your process.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After ANR happens, you would find call stack of related process at `/data/anr/traces.txt` 
After application crashes, you might find **call stack** of crashed application under `/data/tombstones` directory.

Answer (score 5):

See [Android: How to get kernel logs after kernel panic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682306/android-how-to-get-kernel-logs-after-kernel-panic)

It looks like `/data/dontpanic/` should contain some "apanic" files, but only if the kernel's apanic support is enabled, and it worked.  (I haven't seen anything there in my case, but maybe you'll be luckier than I ...)

Answer (score 4):

crash report can be found at default path: /data/anr/

some manufacture place in custom path like: /data/system/ckerror

use cmd:  adb pull /data/anr "dest path"

example: 
in windows cmd prompt:
adb pull /data/anr c:\trace

Answer (score 4):

[The document](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr) states that

Android stores trace information when it experiences an ANR. On older OS releases, there's >a single /data/anr/traces.txt file on the device.

On newer OS releases, there are multiple >/data/anr/anr_* files. You can access ANR traces from a device or emulator by using >Android Debug Bridge (adb) as root:

```
adb root
adb shell ls /data/anr
adb pull /data/anr/<filename>
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually the every crash is stored in traces.txt file under /data/anr/ folder of internal storage. Try checking this file.

Answer (score -1):

I found a file call `crash.txt` inside the directory `/data/Logging` which seems to contain brief stack-traces from the last several crashes that occurred on the device.