# How to pull kernel panic logs from android kernel panic upload mode?

Tags: logging, linux-kernel, crash, panic, android-kernel

During development i faced a crash and a kernel panic upload mode was shown.

Is there a way to connect to the device somehow and pull the logs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for ... source: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682306/android-how-to-get-kernel-logs-after-kernel-panic)
Android creates a RAM console and attempts to save the last kernel message buffer for you in RAM (assuming the power doesn't go out). You can access this file through the proc interface and on system it is word readable:

`cat /proc/last_kmsg`

For more information see the kernel code @ `drivers/staging/android/ram_console.c`