# How to get android boot kernel init messages from smartphone?

Tags: android, android-emulator

How can I debug Android Linux kernel init messages ([printk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printk)) from real Android smartphone or tablet device?

I have compiled [mt6582 kernel for smartphone](https://github.com/452/lenovo-android-phone-linux-kernel), after flashing I can not see what is Linux kernel messages on boot initialization (I have [kernel panic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_panic) and want to see kmsg logs)

I have Lenovo S930 smartphone with ARM mt6582 CPU and trying to use this device for hobby like mini PC with Linux OS with Android. I'm interesting to build Linux kernel from sources. This is done. But I have no understand how to get kernel messages before system start

1. What solution exist for this?
2. How to show kernel messages on smartphone display when android device start (without boot animation)?
3. How to show kernel messages if kernel panic happened and device won't boot?
4. Display, uart, file on TF card, network?
5. How to debug and see?
6. need some special configuration in .config?

**I found similar question:**

1. [Android: How to get kernel logs after kernel panic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682306/android-how-to-get-kernel-logs-after-kernel-panic) 
   But I can't boot to android because kernel what I compile not work and I don't know why and want to see kmsg logs ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [Android StackExchange](http://android.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It belongs in Stack Overflow. The Android Enthusiast community has people who do not program.

Comment: @t0mm13b comunity the same what in stackoverflow and android.stackexchange ? maybe be better to remove tag android from stackoverflow? or move all with this tag to android.stackexchange?
I'm new in this and not know what is better..., please sorry me for question on stackoverflow